# ¿ Como alinear un input de un formulario sin modificar el css del formulario?

Tags: html, css, scss, display

Quiero alinear el `input` de un formulario para alinearlo en el centro.
Sin embargo es un proyecto en el que hay varios archivos de scss y no quiero romperlo.
El formulario no se vera del todo bien ya que utilizamos scss y haya variables no incluidas en el código

Ahora el `input` esta alineado a la izquierda.

he probado con el siguiente código:

```
display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
```

Sin embargo no funciona, el boton de `input` sigue alineado a la izquierda.

Quiza sea poco el ejemplo que muestro

```css
.formulario {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.campo {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    label {
        flex: 0 0 10rem;
    }
    input {
        flex: 1;
        border: none;
        padding: calc(v.$separacion / 4);
        border-radius: 1rem;

        &:disabled {
            background-color: lighten(v.$negro, 30%);
            color: v.$blanco;
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }
    }
}

.boton {
    @include m.boton(v.$azul, v.$blanco);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.boton-eliminar {
    @include m.boton(v.$rojo, v.$blanco);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="nombre-pagina">LOGIN</h1>
<p class="descripcion-pagina">Inicia sesion con tus datos</p>

<form class="formulario" method="POST" action="/">
  <div class="campo">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input 
      type="email"
      id="email"
      placeholder="Tu Email"
      name="email"
    >
  </div>

  <div class="campo">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input 
            type="password"
            id="password"
            placeholder="Tu Password"
            name="password"
        />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Iniciar Sesión">

</form>



<div class="acciones">
    <a href="/crear-cuenta">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? Crear una</a>
    <a href="/olvide">¿Olvidaste tu password?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar `margin: auto` para centrar el botón añadiéndolo directamente en tu estilo de la etiqueta HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="boton" value="Iniciar Sesión" style="margin: auto;">
```

O añadirlo a tu etiqueta CSS:

```
.boton: {
@include m.boton(v.$azul, v.$blanco);
border-radius: 1rem;
margin:auto; /* Añadir a tu css */
}
```